# Unable to find string using Regex in Word 2010

Tags: regex, ms-word

I am trying to find a string in word, I can see 3 of the strings in the document. However, the remaining 600+ of them are not visible.

I'm trying to search using (this is the regex in the external tool I used initially):

```
(ABC-\d+)
```

Using a tool to search in Word I searched for

```
(ABC.*)
```

and all of the results ended up being some form of the following:

```
ABCNormal    -13
```

I don't have a clue how to find out what that even means in this context.

I tried searching IN Word for the following REGEX and it doesn't find any except the 3 that don't have the "normal     " thing.

```
ABC?@[0-9]@
```

That should mean look for ABC some number of characters and some number of numbers.

I have tried turning on the hidden text/etc within the display options, the paragraph icon on the ribbon, anything I an think of.

Any ideas how to figure out how to SEE what this is, and either fix it, or work around it?

In the external tool [(ABC)[^0-9]+(\d+)] finally worked, but I still don't understand how to remove the Normal Text that is in the string that is NOT visible.

For example the string I visibly see

```
ABC-13
```

the text Regex is seeing is

```
ABCNormal      -13
```

Comment: Try `ABC[!-]@-[0-9]@`. It finds `ABCNormal    -1` in `ABCNormal    -13`. Is it what you want? Note you may also use something like `ABC[!-]@-[0-9]{1;100}` to match that whole text. If it is not what you need, please post the example strings and expected output/matches. The only checkbox you need to tick is **Use wildcards** (there is no regex support in Word).

Comment: So, `ABC[!0-9]@[0-9]@` (or ``ABC[!0-9]@[0-9]{1;1000}``) works for you? No idea what you mean by "normal text". If you click **Format** button at the bottom, you can select **Font** and select only the font style you need to match.

Comment: The regex result in my external tool literally outputted the word normal and some spaces (or tabs). Ill try the other suggestions, but not sure if its style related. I cant even copy paste here, because the clipboard doesnt grab the non visible string

Comment: I have not suggested any regex, only the Word wildcard pattern. I thought you need a way to match those ABC-133 with Word pattern. No idea what you need now.

Comment: In Word, to copy hidden text, unhide it first.

Comment: Cant unhide this, havent found a way to make whatever this is visible. And i apologize i misunderstood about regex, but i do need to use regex in the end, (capturing the data for additional processing). I am unsure what you mean by selecting the font style i need to match, as far as i can tell, they are all body style text, for both the one i can find using search, and the one i cant

Comment: What you need is totally obscure. Please describe what you have, what you need, tool that you want to use to obtain the desired result. Also, provide exact steps to repro the problem you have. Otherwise the question must be closed. This is [a regex test](https://regex101.com/r/rB5nL4/2). Is it something you can use?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really show how to reproduce the problem. It's a document I was given, and I was trying to find strings with this characteristic, I was able to work around it (hacky) but it's annoying. Yes it's totally obscure, but I was hoping someone had had a similar problem, it's not a regex problem so much as a Word problem.